# How does QED deal with wavelength of quanta

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, wavelength

Since [QED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) treats photons as individual units (quanta) how does it treat the concept of the "wavelength" associated with the photon?

Comment: There is a very real sense in which QED *doesn't* deal with this. Photons are excitations of the EM field with well defined particle-like properties in the theory and the wave-like behavior is a consequence of summing amplitudes over all coherent means of getting to the final result.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18563/2451 and links therein.

Comment: There is no reason to believe photons can't have a continuous spectrum of energy.  Quantization of energy happen for bound systems like an electron around a nucleus.